# Height of complete N-ary tree

Tags: tree

I have a `complete N-ary tree` that is stored in an array. How can I found out the height of the tree? If the size of the array and the N number).

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-ary_tree#Properties_of_k-ary_trees) tells you that it is

[image: it's like this]

Comment: That is true and I agree but I don't know the number of nodes. I know only the number of elements that are stored in the tree (in my case I need to use an array) and the N(k) factor.